# How can I return all rows with a value that exists in another row?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a Table of Birthdays, labelled Birthday, with the columns "Name", "Day", "Month" and "Year". I want to return the "Name" from every row with a combination of "Day","Month" and "Year" that exists more than once in the table - for example, if I have 5 rows, and in two of them, I have "Day" = 3, "Month" = 12 and "Year" = 1997, the SQL function would return the "Name" from both of those columns, as these values appeared twice in the table, but not any of the other columns, as their "Day", "Month" and "Year" combination is unique, and as such only appears once in the table.

What `WHERE` function would I use here?

I know it would be `SELECT Name FROM Birthday`, but I don't know how to implement the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY` for this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Birthday
GROUP BY Day, Month, Year
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I think _the SQL function would return the "Name" from both of those columns_ means OP wants the names for people sharing a birthday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL window function to do this, see the following code as an example.

```
WITH same_birthday_stat AS (
    Name, 
    Day, 
    Month, 
    Year,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY Day, Month, Year) AS num_shares
FROM
    birthday
)
SELECT
   Name,
   Day,
   Month,
   Year
FROM
   same_birthday_stat
WHERE
   num_shares > 1
```